# SharePoint Claims authentication on external zone : Could not retrieve the IIS Settings. Parameter name: context

Tags: development, 2013, authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

```
SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Context.Request.UrlReferrer, txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

This authenticates the user properly and lets me through to a page that needs authentication on the server itself, but on the extranet zone I get this error :

"Could not retrieve the IIS Settings. Parameter name: context"

Please help! If you have any idea what could be causing this let me know and I'll try to address it. If you need any more code let me know as well.

I simply use the bool that `SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser` gives me to redirect the user appropriately

here's the stack trace ::

```
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message response) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(Uri context, String membershipProviderName, String roleProviderName, String username, String password, SPFormsAuthenticationOption options) at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Uri context, String userName, String password) at Tysabri.SignIn.SignIn.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. I was trying to login through the wrong url (http instead of https)...

Yeap... it was one of those days...